# Turn a data frame column into vector with names as row names

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, r-rownames

I have an output which looks like the following code:

```
data.frame(H = c(1.5,4.5,5,8)) %>% `rownames<-`(c("a","b","c","d"))
    H
a 1.5
b 4.5
c 5.0
d 8.0
```

Ideally, using dplyr, I would like to convert it to a vector like this:

```
  a   b   c   d 
1.5 4.5 5.0 8.0
```

Is there anyway I can do this without defining any new variables and using only the pipe operator?
Using unlist will not result in the desired outcome.

```
data.frame(H = c(1.5,4.5,5,8)) %>% `rownames<-`(c("a","b","c","d")) %>% unlist()

    H1  H2  H3  H4 
    1.5 4.5 5.0 8.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `rownames_to_column` + `deframe` from `tibble`:

```r
library(tibble)
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  deframe()

#  a   b   c   d 
#1.5 4.5 5.0 8.0
```

Another option with `pull`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pull(H, rowname)
```

Or with the exposition pipe `%$%`:

```r
library(magrittr)
df %$% 
  set_names(H, rownames(.))
```

---

For the sake of completeness, the base R one-liner:

```r
setNames(df$H, rownames(df))
```

That can also be piped, with `magrittr`'s `%$%`:

```r
df %$% 
  setNames(H, rownames(.))
```

---

Data:

```r
df <- data.frame(H = c(1.5,4.5,5,8)) %>% 
  `rownames<-`(c("a","b","c","d"))
```

Comment: what does deframe do exactly?

Comment: deframe turns the data.frame into a named vector, with the first column being the values and the second being the names